# How to increase Work In Progress (WIP) limit

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, scrum

In the product backlog items board, there's this WIP display 5/5 for approved PBI and 2/5 for commited PBI

[image]

How can I increase the WIP limit of 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the board, click on Customize columns. The limit is just below the title.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Above your columns should be a "customise columns" button. Click there...

If you don't have that button you need a project or team admin to do it for you..

Comment: Yes, I have that. I can add new columns, but can't change the WIP limit. I am the project admin

Comment: Wip limits are changed on the same page that you configure columns. See the WIP row above the State and WIT rows...